# Difference between two Why...? questions

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

What is the difference between these two questions:

> 1. Why Sweden **makes** the best music?
> 2. Why **does** Sweden **make** the best music?

I suppose there is no difference and one of these is just incorrect. Am I right?

Comment: Ok I am sorry, I will report to moderator to migrate this.

Comment: No need to apologise. It may get migrated by user votes anyway, since we now have the option of doing that ourselves. ***I***, on the other hand, feel a bit sorry that I can't tell you what *kind* of clause your first version represents. Btw - idiomatically, it would always be ***the** best music* (except they don't! :)

Comment: This is fundamentally a do-support question. It may or may not be migrated to ELL (I'll let the community decide that). If it is not migrated, you will find helpful answers under the [tag:do-support] tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

> Why Sweden makes *the* best music, *is because*...

To the question:

> Why does Sweden make *the* best music?

Your first sentence is not a question, but can be used to answer the second sentence which is a question.

Comment: "Why Sweden makes the best music, is because..." is poorly worded. It is redundant.  Instead say "Sweden makes the best music because...".